# defining a var outside of a class used hard in a class giving name error

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I created a class using a variable that is declared out side the class and then tried to use that class from a different file. But after using in a different file, defining the variable form that file, I get a name not defined error.

Originally `fileOne.py` looked like:

```py
dat = 'this string'

class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 5
    def method(self):
        return self.num+dat
```

Now when I change the lay out, so that `dat` is defined in the other file that calls myClass.

Changed `fileOne.py`

```py
#dat = 'this string'

class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 5
    def method(self):
        return self.num+dat
```

`fileTwo.py`

```py
from fileOne import *

dat = "file 2 str"
obj = myClass()
```

I get back

```
NameError: name 'dat' is not defined.
```

I think what I need to do in replace dat with self.dat and pass it as a function parameter. I'm not sure why I'm having this problem.

Comment: That's not just outside the class, it's elsewhere entirely. Make it an explicit argument: `myClass(dat)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So imported modules aren't the same scope as the file it's imported to.

Comment: No, it's not like you're copy-pasting into the same file, it retains its own scope.

Comment: Try `global x = 'some_string'`

Comment: @SeamusSlack no, modules each have their own global scope, in any case, scope is static in Python. You seem to be expecting a sort of dynamic scoping, but that's definitely not what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class code does not import dat itself.
if you want to use configs in different classes, i suggest the following:

```
class SystemConfig():
    dat = 5

class myClass(SystemConfig):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 5
    def method(self):
        return self.num + SystemConfig.dat
```

or from a different file:

```
from fileone import SystemConfig

class myClass(SystemConfig):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 5
    def method(self):
        return self.num + SystemConfig.dat
```

this is much better practice , also lets you run system configuration in one place.